# JavaScript modal will only close after the first time opening it but not after the second time

Tags: javascript

I'm making a note taker app that gives you the option to view said note in a modal whenever the button is clicked. There are two ways the close it by clicking the "X" button or by clicking outside of the modal.
When I proceed with one of these options, the modal will close successfully, but if I open it a second time neither the "X" button or clicking outside seem to work. How could I fix this problem?

```js
class Input {
  constructor(note) {
    this.note = note;
  }
}

class UI {
  addNote(input) {
    // Get table body below form
    const content = document.querySelector(".content");
    // Create tr element
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    // Insert new HTML into div
    row.innerHTML = `
      <td>
        ${input.note}
        <br><br>
        <button class="modalBtn">View Note</button>
      </td>
    `;

    content.appendChild(row);

    // Event listener to make modal
    document.querySelector(".modalBtn").addEventListener("click",       function(e) {
      // Get container div
      const container = document.querySelector(".container");
      // Create div
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      // Assign class to it
      div.className = "modal";
      // Insert HTML into div
      div.innerHTML = `
        <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <div>
            <p>${input.note}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      `;
      // Append the new div to the container div
      container.appendChild(div);
      
      // Get modal
      const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

      // Event listener to close modal when "x" is clicked
      document.querySelector(".closeBtn").addEventListener("click",       function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      });

      // Event listener to close when the window outside the modal       is clicked
      window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (e.target === modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
  }

  // Clear input field
  clearInput() {
    note.value = "";
  }
  
}

// Event listener for addNote
document.getElementById("note-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  // Get form value
  const note = document.getElementById("note").value;
  // Instantiate note
  const input = new Input(note);

  // Instantiate UI
  const ui = new UI();

  // Validate form (make sure input is filled)
  if (note === "") {
    // Error alert
    alert("Please fill in text field!");
  }
  else {
    // Add note
    ui.addNote(input);

    // Clear input field
    ui.clearInput();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

.button {
    background: coral;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}

.button:hover {
    background: #333;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 20% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    animation-name: modalopen;
    animation-direction: 1s;
}

.closeBtn {
    color: #ccc;
    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.closeBtn:hover,
.closeBtnBtn:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.css" integrity="sha512-5fsy+3xG8N/1PV5MIJz9ZsWpkltijBI48gBzQ/Z2eVATePGHOkMIn+xTDHIfTZFVb9GMpflF2wOWItqxAP2oLQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Note Taker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Note Taker</h1>
    <h5>Add A New Note:</h5>
    <form id="note-form">
      <div>
        <label>Note:</label>
        <textarea name="Note" id="note" class="u-full-width">               </textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="button-primary">Add                   Note</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <table>
      <tbody class="content"></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because when you apply

`modal.style.display = "none";`

to the modal, you aren't destroying it, you're only hiding it. Additionally, every time you create a modal, and use

`const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");`

you aren't receiving the new modal you appended to the container, you're receiving the one that it's hidden. That's why the click event doesn't work, because it's being added to the hidden modal. To fix that change,

this:

`modal.style.display = "none";`

to this:

`container.removeChild(modal);`

in both EventListeners

Comment: Thank you! I'm also have trouble opening the modal on the second note whenever it's generated. To add to that, once the second one is generated I'm still able to open the first modal, but not close it. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I think it will be much easier if you're able to identify uniquely the notes you're creating. Right now your code identifies every note as one same note, and that is creating most of your issues.